# Titanium app on iPhone crashes after splash screen

Tags: iphone, titanium-mobile

I am new to titanium. Using a iPhone(Jailbroken)3GS with iOS 5.0.1.
Titanium SDK 1.0.8 and iOS SDK v4.2

Now i m not doing something great, just trying to deploy the sample titanium project on the iPhone device but the app crashes after showing the splash screen.

After seeing the device log i get the message

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x53646570

Also, when i run the xcodeproj that is created by Titanium i get the error

> "Data formatter temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Can't find > dlopen function, so it is not possible to load shared libraries)."

Would be grateful if someone can suggest a workaround.

Comment: @meccan nothing specific i m doing. Any sample program is not running for that matter.

Comment: have you installed the newest Titanium SDK ?

Comment: Yes meccan, i m using the Titanium SDK v 1.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own problem.
I was using a lower version of X-Code(3.2) with iOS SDK 4.2 to deploy to a higher version of iOS 4.2.1.

Turns out we can not do this, the X-Code version has to be higher than that of the iOS present in the device to which it is being deployed.

I upgraded to the latest X-Code i.e. 4.2 with iOS 5.0, and deployed on both iOS 4.2.1 and iOS 5.0.1 and workd like butter.